# Detect blinks in pupillary data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have pupillary data, with `Diam_av` recording averaged pupil diameter, like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Diam_av = c(12.3,13,15.5,0,0,0,0,13.7,0,0,9.98,4,0,8.76)
)
```

Sometimes `Diam_av`is `0`. I assume there to be a blink (i.e., eyes closed) where there are at least 4 consecutive `0` values. I'm trying to *flag*
these `Blinks`, thus:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Blinks = ifelse(Diam_av == 0 & lag(Diam_av) == 0 & lag(Diam_av, 2) == 0 & lag(Diam_av, 3) == 0, 
                         "yes", "no"),
         Blinks = ifelse(lead(Blinks) == "yes"|lead(Blinks,2) == "yes"|lead(Blinks,3) == "yes", 
                         "yes", Blinks))
1    12.30     no
2    13.00     no
3    15.50     no
4     0.00    yes
5     0.00    yes
6     0.00    yes
7     0.00    yes
8    13.70     no
9     0.00     no
10    0.00     no
11    9.98     no
12    4.00   <NA>
13    0.00   <NA>
14    8.76   <NA>
```

While the result is acceptable in terms of `Blinks` detection, there are two issues with the code: (i) it seems bulky and repetitive and (ii) some `Blinks` get changed to `NA` whereas they should be `no`. How can the code be mended?

Comment: What Hz is the capture rate/frame rate? Guessing if you have pupil diameter reported it is 250 but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `rle` and change 4 consecutive 0 values to `'yes'` and rest of them as `'no'`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Blinks = ifelse(with(rle(Diam_av == 0), 
                        rep(values & lengths >= 4, lengths)), 'yes', 'no'))

#   Diam_av Blinks
#1    12.30     no
#2    13.00     no
#3    15.50     no
#4     0.00    yes
#5     0.00    yes
#6     0.00    yes
#7     0.00    yes
#8    13.70     no
#9     0.00     no
#10    0.00     no
#11    9.98     no
#12    4.00     no
#13    0.00     no
#14    8.76     no
```

Comment: Dear Ronak can you please explain a little bit about the test argument of your `ifelse` that you used `with` and `rep`.? Thanks indeed.

Comment: Yes, sure. `rle` actually returns output of shorter length than the input (`Diam_av`). To make it of the same length we use `rep`. We return `TRUE` for only those values that have `Diam_av == 0` and has `lengths >= 4`, rest of them return `FALSE` which is used in `ifelse` to return `yes`/`no`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was interesting to know that we could use `rep` within `with` to manipulate the result of previous expression.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Blinks := c('no', 'yes')[1 + (.N >= 4)],rleid(Diam_av == 0)]
df
    Diam_av Blinks
 1:   12.30     no
 2:   13.00     no
 3:   15.50     no
 4:    0.00    yes
 5:    0.00    yes
 6:    0.00    yes
 7:    0.00    yes
 8:   13.70     no
 9:    0.00     no
10:    0.00     no
11:    9.98     no
12:    4.00     no
13:    0.00     no
14:    8.76     no
```